# Repeating Edit and Delete Button in React via Mui Datatable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, material-ui

**Hi Everyone**, I'm trying to achieve adding edit and delete button in ReactJS using Mui Datatable, but the problem is that it keeps on repeating because of the Map sorry I'm just new in ReactJS anyways, here is my image and my code:

This is an example of my image:
[image]

And This My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

const Client = (props) => (
  <>
      <Link to={"client/edit/" + props.client._id} className="btn btn-primary">
        Edit
      </Link>
      &nbsp;
      <a
        href="client"
        onClick={() => {
          props.deleteClient(props.client._id);
        }}
        className="btn btn-danger"
      >
        Delete
      </a>
   
  </>
);

export default class ClientsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteClient = this.deleteClient.bind(this);

    this.state = { clients: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/clients/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ clients: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  deleteClient(id) {
    axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/clients/" + id).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

    this.setState({
      clients: this.state.clients.filter((el) => el._id !== id),
    });
  }

// This is the map I was talking about:


 clientList() {
    return this.state.clients.map((currentclient) => {
      return (
        <Client
          client={currentclient}
          deleteClient={this.deleteClient}
          key={currentclient._id}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        name: "name",
        label: "Name",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "address",
        label: "Address",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "mobile",
        label: "Mobile",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "email",
        label: "Email",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "gender",
        label: "Gender",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "birthday",
        label: "Birthday",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "facebookPage",
        label: "Facebook Page",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "facebookName",
        label: "Facebook Name",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "existing",
        label: "Existing",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "remarks",
        label: "Remarks",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "Action",
        options: {
          customBodyRender: () => {
            return <>{this.clientList()}</>;
          },
        },
      },
    ];
    const { clients } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style={{ margin: "10px 15px", overflowX: "auto" }}>
          <Link to={"client/create/"} className="btn btn-primary pull-right">
            Add Client Data
          </Link>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <MUIDataTable data={clients} columns={columns} />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help and understanding I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can just not use map in the clientList() function because you are returning (edit, delete ) of all the clients for each row in the table. you also can pass the row data like I will show in the link on each button and have the _id as a hidden column on your table so that you can have access on it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

const Client = (props) => (
  <>
    <Link to={"client/edit/" + props.client._id} className="btn btn-primary">
        Edit
      </Link>
      &nbsp;
    <a
      href="client"
      onClick={() => {
        props.deleteClient(props.client._id);
      }}
      className="btn btn-danger"
    >
      Delete
      </a>

  </>
);

export default class ClientsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteClient = this.deleteClient.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      clients: [{

      }]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios
    .get("http://localhost:5000/clients/")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ clients: response.data });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

  deleteClient(id) {
    axios.delete("http://localhost:5000/clients/" + id).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

    this.setState({
      clients: this.state.clients.filter((el) => el._id !== id),
    });
  }

  // This is the map I was talking about:


  clientList(currentclient) {
    // current cleint her is an array that contain all the columns values for the row specify 
    // assuming that _id will be the first column
      return (
        <Client
          client={currentclient}
          deleteClient={this.deleteClient}
          key={currentclient[0]}
        />
      );
  
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        name: "_id",
        options: {
          display: false,
        }
      }, 
      {
        name: "name",
        label: "Name",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "address",
        label: "Address",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "mobile",
        label: "Mobile",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "email",
        label: "Email",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "gender",
        label: "Gender",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "birthday",
        label: "Birthday",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "facebookPage",
        label: "Facebook Page",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "facebookName",
        label: "Facebook Name",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "existing",
        label: "Existing",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "remarks",
        label: "Remarks",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "Action",
        options: {
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return <>{this.clientList(tableMeta.rowData)}</>;
          },
        },
      },
    ];
    const { clients } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style={{ margin: "10px 15px", overflowX: "auto" }}>
        <Link to={"client/create/"} className="btn btn-primary pull-right">
            Add Client Data
          </Link>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <MUIDataTable data={clients} columns={columns} />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its says when you click edit button the URL says id undefined

Comment: My id is an object id

Comment: can you console.log() the currentclient athe clientList function please to check the data being passed correctly

Answer (score 0):

you can deconstruct clients data from state and then pass it to MUIDataTable

```
const { clients } = this.state;
const rows = clients.map((client) => { 
 return {
// assuming atributes
  name: client.name,
  address: client.address,
  mobile: client.mobile,
  email: client.email,
  gender: client.gender,
  birthday: client.birthday,
 action: <Link to=`client/edit/${client.id}` calssName='btn btn-primary'> Edit </Link> &nbsp; <a href='client' onClick={() => this.deleteClient(client.id)}> delete </a>
}
}
```

and then pass it in data props in MUIDataTable

```
<MUIDataTable data={rows} columns={columns} />
```

Comment: can you please fix your code, it seems to have a lot of error thanks

Comment: or if you use that mui datatable on your code please share us the code

Comment: you can't jsut copy and paste it you have to modify it to fit your code. I will share here my example code

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of a working snippet, tweak it to match you need

```
const rows = orders.map((order) => {
    return {
      ref: <Link to={"/orders/" + order.ref}>{order.ref.slice(0, 8)}</Link>,
      amount: order.amount,
      donated: order.ticketsDetails[0].ticketDonate != "" ? "Yes" : "No",
      date: order.createdAt.slice(0, 16),
    };
  });
  const columns = [
    {
      label: "Ref",
      name: "ref",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Amount",
      name: "amount",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Date",
      name: "date",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
    {
      label: "Donated",
      name: "donated",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: true,
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="orders-container">
      <MUIDataTable columns={columns} data={rows} />
    </div>
  );
```